# how do I use a file to populate the array and compare it with user input c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I wrote a code to populate an array from a file 
and then use that array to compare it with the user input 
The program should ask the user to enter a name or partial name to search for in the
array
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool found = false;
    const int arraySize = 35;
    const int length = 100;
    char contacts[arraySize][length];
    int count = 0;              // Loop counter variable
    ifstream inputFile;         // Input file stream object

    inputFile.open("input.txt"); // Open the file.

                                   // Read the numbers from the file into the array.
                                   // After this loop executes, the count variable will hold
                                   // the number of values that were stored in the array.
    while (count < arraySize && inputFile >> contacts[count])
        count++;
    // Close the file.
    inputFile.close();


    char search[length];                        
    char *fileContact = nullptr;        
    int index;  
    cout << "To search for your contact's number \nplease enter a name or partial name of the person.\n";
    cin.getline(search, length);                            
    for (index = 0; index < arraySize; index++)
    {
        fileContact = strstr(contacts[index], search);
        if (fileContact != nullptr)
        {
            cout << contacts[index] << endl;        
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) cout << "Sorry, No matches were found!";
    return 0;
}
```

and the names in the file are

"Alejandra Cruz, 555-1223"

"Joe Looney, 555-0097"

"Geri Palmer, 555-8787"

"Li Chen, 555-1212"

"Holly Gaddis, 555-8878"

"Sam Wiggins, 555-0998"

"Bob Kain, 555-8712"

"Tim Haynes, 555-7676"

"Warren Gaddis, 555-9037"

"Jean James, 555-4939"

"Ron Palmer, 555-2783"

so the code works, but the problem is
when I write Alejandra for example 
the output is: "Alejandra
the output is supposed to show the full name and the number: 
"Alejandra Cruz, 555-1223"

does anyone know how to fix this? 
thanks!!

Comment: Have you done anything to see what was actually put in your array?  Why not?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In particular, eliminate input from your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
inputFile >> contacts[count]
```

1. Leading whitespace characters are discarded.
2. Non-whitespace characters are read into `contants[count]`.
3. Reading stops when a whitespace character is encountered.

That explains your output.

You need to use [`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) instead.

```
while (count < arraySize && inputFile.get(contacts[count], length) )
    count++;
```

---

#### In response to OP's comment

The above should all the lines of the file up to `arraySize` number of lines.

You could add some debugging output to troubleshoot the problem.

```
while (count < arraySize && inputFile.get(contacts[count], length) )
{
    std::cout << "Read " << count+1 << "-th line.\n" << "\t" << contants[count] << "\n";
    count++;
}
```

Comment: that fixed the issue!! now it show the full name and number if I typed in the first name, 
however, is there any way to show the contact if I typed in the last name ? 
for example if the contacts are:
"Holly Gaddis, 555-8878"
"Warren Gaddis, 555-9037"
can I type the last name which is Gaddis
and show both contacts?

Comment: @fluy619, of course you can. It should work with your posted code.

Comment: I tried to type in Gaddis 
and show both contacts that involves the name 
but the ouput is 
"Sorry, No matches were found!"

Comment: It looks like the array only stores the first name
which means that the other names will not be shown if the user puts their name in the input

Comment: @fluy619, since you accepted the answer, is it fair to assume that your questions/doubts have been answered?

Comment: yes sir, 
I only need to read to the end of the file, 
your method only reads the first line of the file to the array
this is my only concern now